# Xamarin.Forms: Change RelativeLayout constraints afterwards

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to change the constraints of a [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout/) after they have been set one time?

In the documentation I see methods like `GetBoundsConstraint(BindableObject)`, but I think you can only use them if you have a XAML file. For now I'm trying to do this in code. I get `null` if I try

```
RelativeLayout.GetBoundsConstraint(this.label);
```

The only way I found out is to remove the children from the layout and add it with the new constraints again.

**Example:**

```
public class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private BoxView view;
    private bool moreWidth = false;

    public TestPage()
    {
        this.view = new BoxView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
        };

        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "change",
            TextColor = Color.Black,
        };

        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

        this.relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();

        this.relativeLayout.Children.Add(this.view,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.Constant(80),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Height;
            }));

        this.relativeLayout.Children.Add(button,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width / 2;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Height / 2;
            }));

        this.Content = this.relativeLayout;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double width = 0;
        if(this.moreWidth)
        {
            width = 120;
        }
        else
        {
            width = 80;
        }
        var c= BoundsConstraint.FromExpression((Expression<Func<Rectangle>>)(() => new Rectangle(0, 0, width, this.Content.Height)), new View[0]);
        RelativeLayout.SetBoundsConstraint(this.view, c);
        this.relativeLayout.ForceLayout();
        this.moreWidth = !this.moreWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It does not *officially* possible with the current version of Xamarin Forms. The `RelativeLayout` container only recomputes constraints when adding/removing items from its children collection (it caches the solved constraints - presumable for performance). Even though the various constraints are implemented as Bindable Properties, they still do not get recomputed when changed.

I assume that the intention is to someday respect constraint updates, which would be useful with animations for example, but for now it doesn't appear to work that way.

**HOWEVER**, I took a look at the decompiled source for RelativeLayout and it *is* possible to hack together a way around it - but it might not suit your needs, depending on how much functionality you require and how complex your constraint definitions are.

See this example code (the key part is setting the constraint using SetBoundsConstraint, which overrides the internally computed bounds of the added view - and then calling `ForceLayout()`):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        var label = new Label {
            Text = "Test",
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Silver
        };
        var layout = new RelativeLayout ();
        layout.Children.Add (label,
            Constraint.Constant (50),
            Constraint.Constant (100),
            Constraint.Constant (260),
            Constraint.Constant (30));
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = layout
        };

        var fwd = true;
        layout.Animate ("bounce",
            (delta) => {
                var d = fwd ? delta : 1.0 - delta;
                var y = 100.0 + (50.0 * d);
                var c = BoundsConstraint.FromExpression ((Expression<Func<Rectangle>>)(() => new Rectangle (50, y, 260, 30)), new View [0]);
                RelativeLayout.SetBoundsConstraint(label, c);
                layout.ForceLayout ();
            }, 16, 800, Easing.SinInOut, (f, b) => {
                // reset direction
                fwd = !fwd;
            }, () => {
                // keep bouncing
                return true;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! Is it possible to use `BoundsConstraint.FromExpression` together with `Constraint.RelativeToParent`? Or can you only set values for `Rectangle`? What I'm trying to do is to change the width of an element which takes half of the screen. Therefore you have to know the parent height. Currently I'm using `this.Content.Height`, which seems to work. Though I have to test it further out.

Comment: It should work that way as long as all of the constraints on the item you are modifying are Constant or RelativeToParent (the BoundsConstraint is a combination of all four x/y/width/height constraints, so all of those would have to meet this criteria). If any of them use RelativeToView, then you would need to pass those views in an array as the second parameter to `FromExpression()`. It is difficult to tell for sure though if this hack would work for anything but Constant unless you try it out. And of course it's depending on internals so subject to breaking on next XF version.

Comment: I tried to work with `RelativeToParent`, but struggled of using the correct notation. Instead of a constant I tried to use `Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height;})`, but I got a message like *too many parameters*. Did you get it working?

Comment: All of your size computation logic would need to go into the lambda passed to `FromExtression()`. You can't use `Constraint.RelativeToParent()` directly - since that one only works with one dimension of the bounds. In order to have a chance at getting the code exactly right, I would need for you to update your original question to include the code you are using for all of the constraints including the one you are changing later, and it would also be helpful to see the relevant XAML too.

Comment: Currently it is only a test project, where I want to find out which option is best for me. Besides that I can learn from that. So I updated my question with this example. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This possible.
Layout code:

```
<StackLayout RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding XConstaint}" ...>
```

VM code:

```
public Constraint XConstaint
{
  get => _xConstaint;
  set { SetFieldValue(ref _xConstaint, value, nameof(XConstaint)); }
}

public override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();
  XConstaint = Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width - 128; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly , I would try the following

Implement SizeChanged event for relativeLayout

like :-

```
var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout ();

relativeLayout.SizeChanged += someEventForTesting;
```

and invoke the event whenever you want to resize the relative layout or some particular child.

```
public void someEventForTesting(Object sender , EventArgs)
{
var layout = (RelativeLayout)sender ;
//here you have access to layout and every child , you can add them again with new constraint .
}
```

Comment: If the `SizeChanged` event is triggered I have access to the constraints? How can I trigger the `SizeChanged` event with the corresponding `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: `SizeChanged` event doesn't offer any advantages unless maybe if you are using a `Grid` for layout and manually positioning/sizing content items in code. Also, to trigger the `SizeChanged` event you need to resize the container - which can be quite an expensive thing to do if there are a lot of child views.

Comment: @testing- As Keith rightly pointed out , it can be extensive work when you have many children , 
to trigger the event just add anything to particular layout , it will try to change the container and event will be fired , in event , u rewrite whole relativeLayout if you may ,
or change the position of those  children which will be impacted .
Imagine a situation(purely hypothetical one ) :-
you have a layout with 4 buttons on it .
u want to click 4th one and get a new btn appearing right to 4th one.
in this scenario .
on the bttn click event , u can fire the sizeChange ,and do the work there